How to have Lexplore *really* toggle?
Starting with the fact that calling :Lexplore over an over works fine and it "toggles" on and off as most people would assume
When I start B
Vim by opening a directory, :Lexplore will show a second directory listing left of the original directory listing.

run vim somedir/
select one file
now I'm seeing the file and what looks like :Lexplore to the left.
I press my shortcut to :Lexplore

Now, instead of just moving the focus to the left directory listing (or hiding it, I can live with pressing it twice to move focus)... I get TWO directory listings!
Is there a way to make that first directory listing be whatever it needs to be so that Vim knows to "toggle" it as an "Lexplore" region?
Things I already tried:

use Ex instead of Lex

I actually like to have the left pane as most of the time I am looking for a file mentioned in the other file I have open. And my ultra-short-term memory is bad.

About your title, :Lex really "toggles" but you can't expect it to act like a toggle for windows not created with :Lex. Now, start as :Lex… there is no option for that. You an do $ vim +Lex\ somedir to do :Lexplore on directory somedir, though, so you could make an alias or a simple shell function. It might also be possible to make an autocommand in Vim that checks the arguments and does :Lex when the conditions are right.
